# Why is gcc/ld ignore a -L setting?

Tags: gcc, ld

According to the manual page for ld (and gcc used for linking by extension), if a -L option appears on the command line, it applies to all libraries specified by -l and takes precedence over the default search locations. However, that is not working in my link step. I have this on the command line:

-L /users/me/mylib -lpcre -lz

and  /users/me/mylib contains (copies) of libpcre.so and libz.so

These libraries exist in other locations on the system (although not necessarily the same versions) and what I see (with ldd on Linux and otool on Mac) is a path that references the libraries in those locations. Some of those locations are on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which I cannot control in the build environment I am running in) and it appears that somehow those locations are being picked up in preference to my explicit setting with -L.

Just to be clear, this a link step problem and not a runtime problem. There is a lot of info on the web on how to affect/override library locations when executing and I am familiar with all that. In some sense what I am trying to do with the -L is create a completely specified setup. I know I can fix things up with install_name_tool on MacOS but I'd really like to understand why -L isn't doing what it claims to.

One thing I learned using gcc -Wl,-v is that gcc appears to forward all the LD_LIBRARY_PATH directories to ld. However, it places them after the ones explicitly listed by me and man ld says they are searched in order they appear on the line.

Comment: Have you `truss`'d the link step (or `dtruss`'d, &c., as appropriate for your version of OS X) and inspected the search order actually being used (to ensure that it's genuinely looking somewhere else first, vs looking in your intended location and discarding the results as nonviable)?

Comment: Also, is it *really* the GNU `ld` as your title implies, or is it the LLVM implementation that's actually default on MacOS? (Similarly, `gcc` isn't actually the default compiler there -- even the `gcc` command is out-of-the-box a LLVM wrapper, as `gcc --version` will on such systems attest).

Comment: I haven't yet resorted to tools like truss or LD_DEBUG partly because I am not clear on how the information regarding the libraries loaded by the tools themselves and the libraries loaded by ld to satisfy the link command can be distinguised (although I guess ld doesn;t use pcre internally).

Comment: I just added the -Wl,-v to the Mac OS command line and I am now even more baffled. otool reports /opt/local/include as the locations of the pcre/z libs, which is right as they were installed by MacPorts. However, ld does not list /opt/local/include as one of the directories it will search and I am not passing that directory with -L so how the heck did it resolve the library there?

Comment: Oh, and yes, I am using gcc on both Linux and Mac; I know it's a wrapper on Mac to clang, but it's really the ld step that is at issue here and -Wl,-v reports @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-274.1

Comment: One possible problem with my location that may render it non-viable. It only contains an unversioned path, e.g.,  libpcre.so, whereas that is just a link to libpcre.so.1 in the official location and otool/ldd are reporting versionned path so perhaps its critical that the versionned path exists?

Answer (score 4):

> Just to be clear, this a link step problem and not a runtime problem.

From what you describe as the problem, I don't think you are right about this - it sounds like a runtime problem for which you are (justifiably) looking for a solution that you can employ while linking that will solve the problem you have at runtime.

The reason I say it does not appear to be a problem with linking is that it sounds like your linking is working as it is intended. LD (or GCC) are not complaining about the linking, and your linked executables are being produced just fine. The issue you are having is that when you subsequently go to run those executables, the loader is finding libraries other than the ones you intend. The purpose of the `-L` flag during linking is to let the linker know where it can find suitable libraries to use in preparing the linked binary. That is completely separate from where the loader will search for the required libraries at runtime.

As you say, you are already aware that there are ways you could employ at runtime (such as changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) that would avoid the issue by changing the set of paths that the loader searches for libraries, but you'd rather not have to do that because for whatever reason you won't necessarily have control over the runtime environment, which is fair enough.

Luckily, there is a facility that I believe will get you what you want. Take a look at the `ld` option called `-rpath` (see the [GNU ld man page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002drpath_003d_0040var_007bdir_007d-231) for full documentation). Basically, if you add paths during linking using the `-rpath` option, those paths gets stored in the linked executable as preferred locations to find the libraries at runtime, in much the same way they would be searched if included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This should work on Linux or Mac OS X (at least since 10.5).

Passing the `-rpath` option to `ld` via gcc requires using the `-Wl` option to pass the flag through. To obtain an `ld` command line that contains `ld -rpath /custom/path/to/libs` requires a `gcc` invocation something like: `gcc -Wl,-rpath,/custom/path/to/libs`

In short, try replacing what you currently have: `-L/users/me/mylib -lpcre -lz`

With: `-L/users/me/mylib -Wl,-rpath,/users/me/mylib -lpcre -lz`

The resulting executable (or library) will then have `/users/me/mylib` stored as the place to go to find libraries, and it *should* find `libpcre.so` and `libz.so` there without needing to control `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Hmm. My impression was that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would take precedence over the rpath, but I'm realizing that I'm not actually certain that that impression is correct.

Comment: So as I understand it, -rpath is Linux's version of install_name_tool, and that may be a good thing to do irrespective of the my original question about why ld seemed to be finding and storing a different path from the one I provided on my command line with -L. I am about to test this, but I think it is related to the versioning issue I mentioned above. If I do objdump -p libpcre.so it shows that libpcre.so.1 is NEEDED (Elf SONAME field I believe), but my directory does not contain that.

Comment: The experiment of ensuring that both libxxx.so and libxx.so.n, where n is the value recorded in the shared library, did not fix the problem. On Linux it is still recording the location of libxxx as one of -L dirs later on the command line passed through by gcc from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and on Mac OSX is it still recording the Macports dir (/opt/local/lib) even though I am not passing that at all in any way that I can see and ld does not report it in the directories it claims to be searching. This is driving me mad!

Comment: `ld -install_name` (on Mac OS X) is not quite the same thing as `ld -rpath`. The former is intended to make a note of the correct place to find a library, and you use it when building the library. In other words, it is the location where the library will be installed. This is used when linking against a library to record the specified location in the binary that links to it as the correct place for the loader to find it. In your example, you could first use -install_path when building libpcre.so (or modify it with install_name_tool), and then link against that when building your binary.